# python cv2.VideoCapture does not open

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a few avi files which I'm trying to read frame by frame.
I have used opencv 3.1.0 in order to read frames:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
```

and then I just read the frames of cap. This works fine on some of the videos. I took a few more videos recently and the same code comes up empty. I checked:

```
cap.isOpened() # return False
```

and it seems like the video is not opened properly. As far as I'm concerned the only thing that changed is that the new videos are in color whereas the old ones were not. I don't know how that would change anything in the code. I checked that the videos open up just fine in other software (imageJ) so I'm confident the video itself is not the issue.

Any ideas why the new videos are not opening properly? I have not been able to find any information on how to debug this issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to imageio instead of opencv and everything works well

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of time of test & fails on this... 2 things needs to be working

ffmpeg must be installed, you can check if it's installed and working with opencv with this:

```
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

Apparently there's an environment variable OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS that might not be set under some circumstances.... so make sure it is

```
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"
```

tested and working with RSTP from Android using [miv.rtspcamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miv.rtspcamera) and cvlc from Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

I was making the same mistake.

Solution.

1. Use Pycharm
2. Install Anaconda3
3. conda install -c conda-forge opencv  ( open the CMD as an administrator )
4. Select Anaconda3 in PyCharm ( File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter )

AND TEST

```
def VideoPlayer():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("D:\OpenCv4Programmers\datas\TomAndJerry.mp4")

    while (True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows, Python 2.7.4. I tried Opencv installation but it did not work, I also installed ffmpeg. Then I tried this:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `ffmpeg`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you never actually open your `cap`. I have not done this from a video file but to use the camera it looks something like this:

```
import cv2
#instantiate videocapture object (0 is for the default webcam)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    #read frame from video file
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    #if esc key pressed or no more video input
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27 or ret==False:
        break

# When everything done, release the capture

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: My code (using openCV) is identical to yours. The problem is that the cap is not opened properly. In your example ret returns False.

Comment: if you are using windows then you could try `r"file_path"` if there is a `\u` anywhere in the path it will be seen as a unicode escape. Adding the "r" at the beginning is for raw text.